# Optimize performance for date range query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have scenario as below: I have a table `Tblbalance` which contains a date and time column.

When I search using normal between clause in my stored procedure, it will throw error timeout in linq.

I tried to extend default time from 30 sec to 2 min in linq but not worked.

Please help me to get fastest way to return from select query

Sample query I tried is as below:

```
select
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    (select top 1 col from tblname where id = tblbalance.id)
from 
    tblbalance
where 
    datecol between startdate and todate 
order by 
    col3
```

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` rarely makes sense.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What percentage of the rows of `tblbalance` selects (estimate)?

Comment: Please include the primary keys of the tables, as well as the unique constraints, and existing indexes.

Comment: tblbalance and tblname have the same id? can you show the schema?

Comment: table contain almost 5 lakh records on that my query try to fetch records from particular date range . Database is MS sql

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to include one more column in you table and copy numeric of datetime in that column, Also create a index on the newly created numeric column. Then instead of using the datetime column in where clause, try using numeric column.

This way your query will run on index and will be optimised.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).